# magento2 Payment Error when user pays via Mastercard payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Payment Error: INVALID_REQUEST: The total of Item Amount, Tax Amount, Shipping and Handling Amount minus Discount Amount should total the Order Amount (99.00) but is 199.00

Scenario - We have total card value of 199, but here we have used a giftcard of rs 100 so we need to pay only 99 know, when we try to pay we get this error.

- We are trying on test card

https://www.polacin.com/mastercard-payment-gateway-services-mpgs-magento-2.html